# Socialite on Homestead is failing

Tags: laravel-5, homestead, laravel-socialite

I followed the steps to install socialite, after I get redirect back to the website I get this error. I tried to find the root cause but failed to do so

```
    in Middleware.php line 68
    at Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(object(Response)) in Promise.php line 199
    at Promise::callHandler('1', object(Response), array(object(Promise), object(Closure), null)) in Promise.php line 165
    at Promise::GuzzleHttp\Promise\{closure}(object(Response)) in FulfilledPromise.php line 39
    at FulfilledPromise::GuzzleHttp\Promise\{closure}() in TaskQueue.php line 60
    at TaskQueue->run() in CurlMultiHandler.php line 96
    at CurlMultiHandler->tick() in CurlMultiHandler.php line 123
    at CurlMultiHandler->execute(true) in Promise.php line 240
    at Promise->invokeWaitFn() in Promise.php line 217
    at Promise->waitIfPending() in Promise.php line 261
    at Promise->invokeWaitList() in Promise.php line 219
    at Promise->waitIfPending() in Promise.php line 62
    at Promise->wait() in Client.php line 130
    at Client->request('get', 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?', array('query' => array('prettyPrint' => 'false'), 'headers' => array('Accept' => 'application/json', 'Authorization' => 'Bearer ya29.mwEAinsjKtGZl4rV1gPXFJ2OjU1xpV1LRhTUYSQq7LN-8V71mmlRgFQxbScucm0VI00D--MbeqzyVQ'))) in Client.php line 88
    at Client->__call('get', array('https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?', array('query' => array('prettyPrint' => 'false'), 'headers' => array('Accept' => 'application/json', 'Authorization' => 'Bearer ya29.mwEAinsjKtGZl4rV1gPXFJ2OjU1xpV1LRhTUYSQq7LN-8V71mmlRgFQxbScucm0VI00D--MbeqzyVQ')))) in GoogleProvider.php line 86
    at Client->get('https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?', array('query' => array('prettyPrint' => 'false'), 'headers' => array('Accept' => 'application/json', 'Authorization' => 'Bearer ya29.mwEAinsjKtGZl4rV1gPXFJ2OjU1xpV1LRhTUYSQq7LN-8V71mmlRgFQxbScucm0VI00D--MbeqzyVQ'))) in GoogleProvider.php line 86
    at GoogleProvider->getUserByToken('ya29.mwEAinsjKtGZl4rV1gPXFJ2OjU1xpV1LRhTUYSQq7LN-8V71mmlRgFQxbScucm0VI00D--MbeqzyVQ') in AbstractProvider.php line 188
    at AbstractProvider->user() in AuthController.php line 85
    at AuthController->handleProviderCallback('google')
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(AuthController), 'handleProviderCallback'), array('provider' => 'google')) in Controller.php line 255
    at Controller->callAction('handleProviderCallback', array('provider' => 'google')) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 163
    at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(AuthController), object(Route), 'handleProviderCallback') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 111
```

Answer (score 0):

I traced the error, it is not related to guzzle at all, it is has to deal with Google API. you need to enalbe Google+ API from the developer console. otherwise you will get this error which basically means you are forbidden from accessing Google+ information